# What is the use of "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track"

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

What is the use of "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track" ? As it is used to track our application using Application Insights but in page refresh or page break it stop tracking after that.

Comment: Found this in my Chrome console as a 400 Invalid instrumentation key . This page is the only Google result and I find I had already up-voted it. sigh.

Comment: Still happening.

Answer (score 29):

It's an old question but (un)forturnately still relevant...

See: [http://davidbanks.blog/Posts/redirectingApplicationInsights (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220111011611/http://davidbanks.blog/Posts/redirectingApplicationInsights)

It seems that the telemetry for Application Insights is currently (on the 11 May 2017) going to two endpoints:

- `dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` is the endpoint for most of the metrics
- `rt.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track` seems to be exclusively for  "Quick Pulse Service"

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses

Comment: Hi Herre, once again, some external link fails to open. Could you summarize any valuable information if they are useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is no longer tracking, check if it is returning a `439` error.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/721870/error-439-application-insights), if you hit the monthly quota in Application Insights, and no one is viewing it, collection will not resume until someone views it in the Azure portal.

So either view your data in App Insights, set a higher quota, or fix what is filling it up with logs/errors.