# How to stop Visual Studio 2022 sending requests to dc.services.visualstudio.com

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I installed vs 2022 today and when running my project I suddenly se all these requests firing in my web front-end

```
https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track
```

Does anyone know why this would suddenly start happening after upgraing to vs 2022?

[image]

I don't want to see these requests in local dev environment. How can I remove them?

---

I tried checking this box but it didn't help:

[image]

I also tried ignoring the AI dependency after right-clicking clicking `Project -> Configure Application Insights`, but that seems to do nothing:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148355/what-is-the-use-of-https-dc-services-visualstudio-com-v2-track

Comment: @DavidG Thanks David, any idea how I can disable this? I don't need these requests firing when I'm working locally in VS

Comment: Here's an open ticket on the VS forum about it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Application-Insights-/1578628 the MS response is that it's caused by the application insights SDK but there are many replies explaining that it's happening without that SDK in use

Comment: Really an annoyance. Tempted to add dc.services.visualstudio.com 127.0.0.1 to system hosts file

Comment: This issue seems to be caused by the AppInsights SDK and not Visual Studio. Please file a ticket with that product at https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/main/BASE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Extensibility/Implementation/Endpoints/Constants.cs#L9)

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN when trying to raise this issue on the linked github, I was sent back to MS (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2490)

Answer (score 6):

You can follow my steps to disable Application Insights when you debug.

First you can add

```
#if !DEBUG
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
#endif
```

in `ConfigureServices`.

And second you need add

```
#if DEBUG
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
TelemetryDebugWriter.IsTracingDisabled = true;
#endif
```

in `Configure`.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately changing these didn't remove the logs

Answer (score 3):

I found several solutions (the 1st option helped me):

### 1. Disable browser connection

Tools > Options > Project & Solutions > ASP.NET Core

**CSS Hot Reload - Disabled**

May you need to restart VS after changing that option.

---

Go to the browser link toolbar and click the arrow pointing down - shown below.
Turn off "Enable browser link" so that it no longer has a check mark
Restart Visual Studio after you have done this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq8uf.png)

### 2. Disable Insights

Tools > Options > Project & Solutions > Web Projects

turn on "**Disable local Application Insights for ASP.NET Core web projects**"

---

In file Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
...
#if !DEBUG
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
#endif
...
}
```

and:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
...
#if DEBUG
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
TelemetryDebugWriter.IsTracingDisabled = true;
#endif
...
}
```

### 3. Edit file hosts

Add in file hosts:

- 127.0.0.1   dc.services.visualstudio.com
- 127.0.0.1   rt.services.visualstudio.com

Comment: Option 3 works perfectly to disable telemetry on Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this. We've investigated it and identified the source of that request. The request has been removed and the fix will be included in an upcoming release. You can keep track of when it is released by following this [feedback ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Application-Insights-/1578628), to which other similar tickets were duped.

Comment: Hi Tim, any update on this? I upgraded to the new version today, but still seeing the requests. Also, do you have any thoughts on this, related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470877/why-does-vs-2022-have-log-all-this-garbage-in-the-console

Comment: Still not available on 14 Jan 2022. Why do I get the feeling that this request was not included in error, and is just part of MS's plan to jam telemetry into everything?

Comment: Hi @Bassie Sorry I missed your earlier message - got lost over the holidays.

Sorry to disappoint but there's no conspiracy here. The fix is line for the next release (17.1 Preview 3 - the preview 2 cut off had already happened before the holidays when the fix was committed). The feedback ticket above is properly tracking it and will let you know when it has been released. Shouldn't be much longer.

Comment: @Bassie It looks like the linked question in your first comment was deleted, but I think I found the replacement so I'll respond there.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error finally found the root causes of this issue
I had an issue where I added Microsoft Application insights via NPM to my app, this app will be loaded inside an iframe inside a website, but the application insights that I added not only tracked my app error but also all the global errors that happened inside the sites in which the app was loaded.Also, there was a track call going for every error and request.

First, all the global errors that have been captured even from the parent site were due to the connection string configuration

```
  appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
    connectionString: INSTRUMENTATION_KEY
  } });
```

when you configure ApplicationInsights like this using the connection string it has no restrictions and logs all the window.onerror as exceptions to that ApplicationInsights
Instead, use the instrumentation key

```
   appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
    instrumentationKey: INSTRUMENTATION_KEY
  } });
```

This stopped sending most of the global window.onerror to my ApplicationInsights
But still, some track calls were being made to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track after every Ajax call to stop this I added some explicit properties to my ApplicationInsights

```
  appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
    instrumentationKey: INSTRUMENTATION_KEY,
    disableAjaxTracking: true, // Disable automatic AJAX tracking
    disableFetchTracking: true,
    disableExceptionTracking: true // Disable automatic exception tracking 
  } });
```

This completely solved my issue, and no more track calls were being made from the site except the ones I explicitly made.
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

for me, changing the `@microsoft/applicationinsights-web` version to the latest in package.json helped in my case. This request was firing automatically after when I was running the cypress test.

"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.0.5"

Hope it helps.