# Why is my WebAPI making calls to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am running Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.2), and I just created a new Web API Core project from the template.  I enabled Microsoft Identity as the identity provider (Azure AD).

Then I ran the solution and it brings up swagger.  I did a "Try It Out" on the WeatherForecast operation. (Which failed with a 401 because the template does not enable swagger's security abilities.)

But the odd part is that in my Chrome DevTools, after the 401 line, I got this:

[image: traking url]

Why is my new project (from the standard Web API Core template) making calls to an external site?  I don't have anything in my code referencing `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track`.  There are strict privacy laws around the code I write, and I get very nervous when there are suddenly random calls to unknown URLs.

I did some googling, and it seems this is related to something called "Microsoft Telemetry" or "Application Insights".  But all the fixes that I can find have you removing or disabling code that does not come in the default WebAPI template.  Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69907632/16241).

I did see a fix that had you modify the hosts files so that the traffic would not leave your machine.  That seems like it would work, but then I have to get this change done to my production machines (which I would rather not).

Why is this in there by default?

**And more importantly how can I remove it so that it is not in my code when it is deployed to production?**

Comment: Can you please share the exact steps you took to create this project? It looks like that your app is instrumented with Application Insights.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's this bug https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Application-Insights-/1578628

The fix is to upgrade your Visual Studio (for example 17.3.0 as of June 2022).